# Constructing an active verb out of a passive word

Tags: etymology, terminology, construction

Consider the following words:

[capture](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capture):

> to take captive, to gain control of especially by force; to gain or win especially through effort

[captive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/captive):

> taken and held as or as if a prisoner of war; kept within bounds, confined

"capture" is an *active* verb -- i.e. doing [to] someone/something else, whereas "captive" is *passive* -- i.e. having been captured by the person/thing doing the capturing, which brings us to

[captivate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/captivate), descended from a passive word but with an active sense (not as strong a word as "capture" and without any sort of physical connotation, but roughly synonymous):

> to influence and dominate by some special charm, art, or trait and with an irresistible appeal

---

Similarly (albeit maybe slightly less convincing):

> <s>rust -> rustic -> rusticate</s> (not actually related, thanks @psmears)

or beginning with a more archaic verb:

> prognose -> prognostic -> prognosticate

---

Is there a linguistic or etymological term for this sort of transformation from passive to active?  Also any other examples?

Comment: "rustic" and "rusticate" are unrelated to "rust" - the former two are from Latin (_rus_, _ruris_ = country, countryside); "rust" is from Old English and related to "red" (cf "russet").

Comment: @psmears ah good to know, thanks!

Comment: And _captive_ is a noun, not a verb, and therefore can't be "passive". You seem to have an odd idea what _passive_ means. It's a verb construction with auxiliary _be_ followed by a past participle. _Captive_ does not meet the specs.

Comment: @JohnLawler It can be a noun or an adjective, e.g. *captive* prisoners, having been captured, or a *captive* audience.  I agree with you that's how we got there, but I'm not sure it disqualifies the word.

Comment: Like all nouns, it can occur in noun compounds; but parts of speech vary and can't be looked up in the dictionary. Dictionaries report usage, much later than it appears in the language -- they don't tell you what not to do, they only report on some of the possibilities. And it's not passive, any more than _stone_ or _matrix_ is passive.

Comment: 'Passive' is almost always required to be the grammatical usage when used on ELU, Erich.  John kicked the ball' [active usage] ↔ The ball was kicked {by John} [passive usage].  You might use the terms 'dynamic' (for 'kick'), 'stative' (for 'stay' {in the cell}), and 'inchoative' (for 'imprison'). But these describe types of _verbs_. 'Describing an action' and 'describing a state' are probably best here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough - grammatically speaking - in that "passive" doesn't apply to an adjective (at least in English).  Your suggestions are far better in that regard, and thank you.  I'll consider rewording using those descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

The word "captive" is not passive. Nouns do not have voice, and "captive" is not derived from the passive of "to capture"; the passive of "to capture" is "to be captured."

But there is something to your intuition. [As Wiktionary explains](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/captive#Noun), "captive" comes from Latin "captivus," which in turn comes from "captus," the perfect passive participle of "capio." ["Capture"](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/capture) comes ultimately from "capturus," the future active participle of the same word. So etymologically the two come from the same word: "captive" from a passive voice form and "capture" from an active voice one.